# Save as png dynamically in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am very new to Matlab so sorry if this is trivial. I have a matlab code done by another student and I am trying to do something. There is a pattern generated which should be saved to a .png image. 
For now, it asks for user input on where to save the file like following:

```
[filename,pathname,dummy] = uiputfile('*.png');
imwrite(image_blobs,[pathname filename '.png'],'png');
```

I need it to be saved as soon as the pattern is generated, I did try to do the following:

```
pathname='H:\matlab_modified';
filename='pic';
imwrite(image_blobs,[pathname filename '.png'],'png');
```

but this will not work.
I also did try the save but the save will not save it as image, right ?
Any idea how to do it ?

thanks

Comment: I think you just forgot a backslash. Have you checked the root directory of `H:\ `? You should have a file named `matlab_modifiedpic.pnc` directly in `H:\ `...

Comment: Thanks, yeah my bad , I should have put a backslash at the end :-) thnx again

Comment: @Momo: you could use the [FULLFILE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fullfile.html) function to produce more portable code (on Windows it uses 'backslash', on Mac and Linux it uses 'forwardslash')

Answer (score 1):

```
pathname='H:\matlab_modified';
filename='pic';
% build full filename from path, filename and extension
full_filename = fullfile(pathname, filename, '.png');
imwrite(image_blobs, full_filename, 'png');
```